# Why arraylist1 = arraylist2 doesnot assign values of arraylist2 to arraylist1?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

This makes the `RecyclerView` blank:

```
      public void onTicketsFetched(SupportTicketModel[] fetchedTickets) {
            ArrayList<SupportTicketModel> ticketModelsUpdated = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fetchedTickets));
            ticketModels.clear();
            ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated;
            ticketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

Whereas this works:

```
     public void onTicketsFetched(SupportTicketModel[] fetchedTickets) {
            ArrayList<SupportTicketModel> ticketModelsUpdated = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fetchedTickets));
            ticketModels.clear();
            ticketModels.addAll(ticketModelsUpdated);
            ticketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

**DIFFERENCE**:

- **First**:   ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated;
- **Second**: ticketModels.addAll(ticketModelsUpdated);

As far as I have understood, both `ticketModels` and `ticketModelsUpdated` when done `ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated` will essentially refer to the same list. So technically, `ticketModels` should have every value of `ticketModelsUpdated`. But this is giving me error. Any idea ?

I understand `ticketMOdels.AddAll(ticketModelsUpdated)` will create two lists of same value. And it is working fine.

So whats up ?

Comment: declare "ArrayList<SupportTicketModel> ticketModelsUpdated" as global and then assign it "ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated;" because you are assigning your list in void method which is local and will get destroyed. so you have to declare it gloabally

Comment: @android i did it and it's still not working!

Answer (score 0):

in Java, lists work by reference. In the first part, you are changing both the memory addresses and values of your items, while, in the second part, you are changing the values only. that's why your second solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in your adapter

Assuming you pass `ticketModels` to your adapter and you save this reference in a list variable.

When you do

```
ticketModels.addAll(ticketModelsUpdated);
```

the internal adapter list pointer is always referencing ticketModels. So, it works.

But with this:

```
ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated;
```

You are changing the ticketModels pointer, but your adapter is always pointing to the previous ticketModel value.

You should also update your adapter list pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you share the same memory address of array elements between two links: `ticketModels` and `ticketModelsUpdated`. It means you can have access to the same elements from two different points of entry.

In the second case you create the same elements using new memory address. It means `ticketModels` isn't sharing the same memory space with `ticketModelsUpdated`.

Despite `ticketModelsUpdated` is local variable, allocated memory will live until there is reference to this address. So, in my understanding `ticketModels` should have access to all elements even after `ticketModelsUpdated` is destroyed. Both cases should work.

**EDIT:** Looks like you bind your adapter to the reference of `ticketModels` and not to the values of `ticketModels`. That is why your method `ticketModels.clear()` clears old allocated memory space where your adapter was linked to. So in the first case you change the link to new memory space for your `ticketModels` while your adapter still references to the cleared memory space. And in second case you keep the reference to the old memory space and fill cleared data there with new elements.

It's only my guess since you didn't provide any information how you bind your adapter with `ticketModels`.

Answer (score 0):

**DIFFERENCE:**

- First: ticketModels = ticketModelsUpdated;
- Second: ticketModels.addAll(ticketModelsUpdated);

First case: This case assigns the reference of ticketModelsUpdated to ticketModels. So whenever the "ticketModels" list gets modified, the "ticketModelsUpdated" also gets modified. That's why this case didn't work.

Second case: This case only assign the value of ticketModelsUpdated to ticketModels. So the changes in "ticketModels" list will not modify the "ticketModelsUpdated" list.